# Dynamically populating a bootstrap vertical multi level submenu in C#

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website which contains a dynamically generated menu, due to layout changes my current method needs to be changed.

The old method:

```
// Create the main menu with quantities and totals
public static StringBuilder CreateMenu(string iso, decimal languageID, string alias, string startItemsFromAlias = null, bool showAllItems = false, string url = null, int headerLevel = 3)
{
    List<GroupLite> groups = BL_Group.GetMenuStructure(languageID, alias, startItemsFromAlias, showAllItems, 1);

    StringBuilder menu = new StringBuilder();
    int i = -1, j = 0;
    bool isParent, lastItem;
    string className, href;
    headerLevel = headerLevel == 0 ? 2 : headerLevel;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url) && !url.EndsWith("/"))
        url += "/";

    if (groups.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GroupLite item in groups)
        {
            className = "";

            // Determine the right opening/closure for our tags
            j = (item.Level.Length - item.Level.Replace(".", "").Length);

            if (i != -1)
                if (j == i)
                    menu.Append("</li>");
                else if (j > i)
                    menu.Append("<ul>");
                else if (j < i)
                {
                    menu.Append("</li>");

                    for (int k = j; k < i; k++)
                        menu.Append("</ul>");

                    menu.Append("</li>");
                }

            i = j;

            // Every first and last items has a class attached to them (first|last)
            if (j == 0)
                lastItem = !groups.Exists(r => (r.Level.Length - r.Level.Replace(".", "").Length) == j && r.Position > item.Position);
            else
                lastItem = !groups.Exists(r => r.Level.StartsWith(item.Level.Substring(0, item.Level.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)) && (r.Level.Length - r.Level.Replace(".", "").Length) == j && r.Position > item.Position);

            if (item.Position == 1)
                className = "first ";

            if (lastItem)
                className += "last ";

            // Check if our item is the parent of other items (necessary for the url)
            isParent = groups.Where(r => r.Level.StartsWith(item.Level + ".")).Count() > 0;

            // Mark the current URL as active if necessary
            if (BL_Group.GetOverviewByAlias(languageID, iso, item.Alias).Count == 0)
                href = Link.Catalogue(iso, item.Alias);
            else
                href = Link.Group(iso, item.Alias);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                if (url.StartsWith(href) || isParent)
                    className += " active ";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
                className = " class='" + className.Trim() + "'";

            menu.Append("<li" + className + "><a href='" + href + "'>" + item.Name + "</a>");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
            menu.Append("</li></ul>");

        menu.Append("</li>");
    }

    return menu;
}
```

this returns:

```html
<li class='first'><a href='/nl/nieuw/aanbod'>Nieuw</a></li>
<li><a href='/nl/geschenkverpakkingen/aanbod'>Geschenkverpakkingen</a></li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/gezelschapsspelen'>Gezelschapsspellen</a><ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/gezelschapsspelen-kinderen-8j'>Gezelschapsspelen kinderen -8j</a><ul>
        <li class='first  active'><a href='/nl/bordspel-8j-1'>Bordspel -8j</a><ul>
            <li class='first'><a href='/nl/solo-spel-8j/aanbod'>Solo spel -8j</a></li>
            <li><a href='/nl/vanaf-2-spelers-8j-1/aanbod'>Vanaf 2 spelers -8j</a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vanaf-3-spelers-8j/aanbod'>Vanaf 3 spelers -8j</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='last  active'><a href='/nl/kaartspel-reisformaat-8j'>Kaartspel reisformaat -8j</a><ul>
            <li class='first'><a href='/nl/solo-spel-8j-1/aanbod'>Solo spel -8j</a></li>
            <li><a href='/nl/vanaf-2-spelers-8j-2/aanbod'>Vanaf 2 spelers -8j</a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vanaf-3-spelers-8j-1/aanbod'>Vanaf 3 spelers -8j</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last  active'><a href='/nl/gezelschapsspelen-volwassenen-kinderen-8j'>Gezelschapsspelen volwassenen & kinderen +8j</a><ul>
        <li class='first  active'><a href='/nl/bordspel-8j'>Bordspel +8j</a><ul>
            <li class='first'><a href='/nl/vanaf-2-spelers-8j/aanbod'>Vanaf 2 spelers +8j</a></li>
            <li><a href='/nl/solo-spel-8j-2/aanbod'>Solo spel +8j</a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vanaf-3-spelers-8j-2/aanbod'>Vanaf 3 spelers +8j</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='last  active'><a href='/nl/kaartspel-reisformaat-8j-1'>Kaartspel reisformaat +8j</a><ul>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vanaf-3-spelers-8j-3/aanbod'>Vanaf 3 spelers +8j</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/bio-natuurvoeding'>Bio & Natuurvoeding</a><ul>
    <li class='first  active'><a href='/nl/bakproducten'>Bakproducten</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/bakbenodigdheden/aanbod'>Bakbenodigdheden</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/bind-geleermiddelen/aanbod'>Bind- & geleermiddelen</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/bloem-meel/aanbod'>Bloem & meel</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/desserts-dessertbereidingen/aanbod'>Desserts & dessertbereidingen</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/zemelen-en-kiemen/aanbod'>Zemelen en kiemen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/beschuiten-rijstwafels'>Beschuiten & rijstwafels</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/crackers-beschuiten/aanbod'>Crackers & beschuiten</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/essenenbrood/aanbod'>Essenenbrood</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/rijst-maiswafels/aanbod'>Rijst- & maïswafels</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/soepstengels-toast/aanbod'>Soepstengels & toast</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/conserven-tapas'>Conserven & Tapas</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/antipasti/aanbod'>Antipasti</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/bereide-gerechten/aanbod'>Bereide gerechten</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/fruitconserven/aanbod'>Fruitconserven</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/groenteconserven/aanbod'>Groenteconserven</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/pesto-tapas/aanbod'>Pesto & tapas</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/peulvruchten/aanbod'>peulvruchten</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/soepen/aanbod'>Soepen </a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/visconserven-1/aanbod'>Visconserven</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/vleesvervangers-vegetarisch/aanbod'>Vleesvervangers vegetarisch</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vleesconserven/aanbod'>Vleesconserven</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/broodbeleg'>Broodbeleg</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/chocopasta/aanbod'>Chocopasta</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/confituur-stropen/aanbod'>Confituur & stropen</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/honing/aanbod'>Honing</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/noten-zadenpasta/aanbod'>Noten- & zadenpasta</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vegetarisch-broodbeleg/aanbod'>Vegetarisch broodbeleg</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/deegwaren-pastas'>Deegwaren - Pasta's</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/kamut-quinoa-etc/aanbod'>Kamut, quinoa etc.</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/spelt/aanbod'>Spelt</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/tarwe/aanbod'>Tarwe</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/dranken-1'>Dranken</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/alcoholvrij-2/aanbod'>Alcoholvrij</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/frisdranken/aanbod'>Frisdranken</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/groentesappen-1/aanbod'>Groentesappen</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/koude-dranken/aanbod'>Koude dranken</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/melk/aanbod'>Melk</a></li>
        <li class='active'><a href='/nl/plantaardige-dranken'>Plantaardige dranken</a><ul>
            <li class='first'><a href='/nl/sojadranken/aanbod'>Sojadranken</a></li>
            <li><a href='/nl/rijstdranken/aanbod'>Rijstdranken</a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/noten-granen-dranken/aanbod'>Noten- & granen dranken</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='/nl/siropen-diksappen/aanbod'>Siropen & diksappen</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/vruchtensappen/aanbod'>Vruchtensappen</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/water/aanbod'>Water</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/noten-zaden-etc'>Noten & Zaden etc.</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/gedroogde-vruchten/aanbod'>Gedroogde vruchten</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/noten/aanbod'>Noten</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/pitten-zaden/aanbod'>Pitten & zaden</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/ontbijt'>Ontbijt</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/cornflakes/aanbod'>Cornflakes</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/crunchy-flakes/aanbod'>Crunchy flakes</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/gepofte-ontbijtgranen/aanbod'>Gepofte ontbijtgranen</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/muesli-1/aanbod'>Muesli</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/ontbijtpappen/aanbod'>Ontbijtpappen</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vlokken/aanbod'>Vlokken</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/granen-peulvruchten-1'>Granen & peulvruchten</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/granenmix/aanbod'>Granenmix</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/kiemzaden/aanbod'>Kiemzaden</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/linzen-bonen/aanbod'>Linzen & bonen</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/peulvruchten-1/aanbod'>Peulvruchten</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/quinoa-couscous-bulgur/aanbod'>Quinoa, couscous & bulgur</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/rijst-1/aanbod'>Rijst</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/oosterse-macrobiotische-voeding'>Oosterse & macrobiotische voeding</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/deegwaren-noedels/aanbod'>Deegwaren & noedels</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/geleermiddel/aanbod'>Geleermiddel</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/macrobiotiek-keukengerei/aanbod'>Macrobiotiek keukengerei</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/soepen-bouillons/aanbod'>Soepen & bouillons</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/specialiteiten-smaakmakers/aanbod'>Specialiteiten & smaakmakers</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/zeewieren/aanbod'>Zeewieren</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/plantaardige-desserts/aanbod'>Plantaardige desserts</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/zoete-versnaperingen'>Zoete versnaperingen</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/chocolade/aanbod'>Chocolade</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/koeken/aanbod'>Koeken</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/repen-bars/aanbod'>Repen & bars</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/snoep/aanbod'>Snoep</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last  active'><a href='/nl/zoute-versnaperingen'>Zoute versnaperingen</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/aardappelchips/aanbod'>Aardappelchips</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/borrelhapjes-zoutjes/aanbod'>Borrelhapjes & zoutjes</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/groentenchips/aanbod'>Groentenchips</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/voedingssupplementen'>Voedingssupplementen</a><ul>
    <li><a href='/nl/allergieen/aanbod'>Allergieën</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/anti-stress-relaxatie/aanbod'>Anti-stress & relaxatie</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/antioxidanten/aanbod'>Antioxidanten</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/bloedsomloop/aanbod'>Bloedsomloop</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/detox-zuiveren/aanbod'>Detox & Zuiveren</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/energie-vitaliteit/aanbod'>Energie & Vitaliteit</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/geheugen/aanbod'>Geheugen</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/haar-nagels/aanbod'>Haar & Nagels</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/huid/aanbod'>Huid</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/lever-gal/aanbod'>Lever & Gal </a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/luchtwegen/aanbod'>Luchtwegen</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/nachtrust/aanbod'>Nachtrust</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/ogen-gezichtsvermogen/aanbod'>Ogen & Gezichtsvermogen</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/omega-vetzuren/aanbod'>Omega-vetzuren</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/probiotica-darmflora/aanbod'>Probiotica - Darmflora</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/slanke-lijn/aanbod'>Slanke lijn </a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/soepelheid-gewrichten/aanbod'>Soepelheid & Gewrichten</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/spijsvertering/aanbod'>Spijsvertering</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/sport/aanbod'>Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/stoelgang-darmtransit/aanbod'>Stoelgang - Darmtransit</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/stofwisseling/aanbod'>Stofwisseling</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/urinewegen-blaas/aanbod'>Urinewegen & Blaas</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/vitaminen-mineralen/aanbod'>Vitaminen & Mineralen</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/voor-kinderen/aanbod'>Voor Kinderen </a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/voor-de-man/aanbod'>Voor de Man </a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/voor-de-vrouw/aanbod'>Voor de Vrouw</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/voor-senioren/aanbod'>Voor Senioren</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/weerstand-immuniteit/aanbod'>Weerstand - Immuniteit</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/bijenproducten-apitherapie/aanbod'>Bijenproducten - apitherapie</a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/nl/gemoedstoestand/aanbod'>Gemoedstoestand</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/lichaamsverzorging'>Lichaamsverzorging</a><ul>
    <li class='first  active'><a href='/nl/bad-doucheproducten'>Bad- & doucheproducten</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/bad-en-douchegel-schuim/aanbod'>Bad- en douchegel & schuim</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/badolie/aanbod'>Badolie</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/zeep/aanbod'>Zeep</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/deodoranten-parfums/aanbod'>Deodoranten & parfums</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/gezichtsverzorging/aanbod'>Gezichtsverzorging</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/haarverzorging'>Haarverzorging</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/haarkleuring-kleurshampoo/aanbod'>Haarkleuring & kleurshampoo</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/haarolielotion/aanbod'>Haarolie/lotion</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/shampoo-conditioner/aanbod'>Shampoo & conditioner</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/haargelspraymousse/aanbod'>Haargel/spray/mousse</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/anti-luizenproducten/aanbod'>Anti-luizenproducten</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/hand-en-voetverzorging/aanbod'>Hand- en voetverzorging</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/huidproducten'>Huidproducten</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/bodylotions-huidolien/aanbod'>Bodylotions & huidoliën</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/hydrolaten/aanbod'>Hydrolaten</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/massageolie/aanbod'>Massageolie</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/hygiene-2'>Hygiëne</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/lichaamshygiene/aanbod'>Lichaamshygiëne</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vrouwelijke-hygiene/aanbod'>Vrouwelijke hygiëne</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/mondhygiene'>Mondhygiëne</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/extra-mondverzorging/aanbod'>Extra mondverzorging</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/tandpasta/aanbod'>Tandpasta</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/natuurcosmetica/aanbod'>Natuurcosmetica</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/therapeutische-zalven-sprays/aanbod'>Therapeutische zalven & sprays</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/verzorging-voor-de-man'>Verzorging voor de man</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/douche-deo-man/aanbod'>Douche & deo man</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/gelaatsverzorging-man/aanbod'>Gelaatsverzorging man</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/scheergerei-aftershave/aanbod'>Scheergerei & aftershave</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/nl/zonneproducten/aanbod'>Zonneproducten</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/speelgoed-schoolgerei'>Speelgoed & Schoolgerei</a><ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/schoolgerei'>Schoolgerei</a><ul>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/brooddozen-drinkflessen/aanbod'>Brooddozen & drinkflessen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/knutselen'>Knutselen</a><ul>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/boetseren-verven/aanbod'>Boetseren & verven </a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/verkleden-poppenkast/aanbod'>Verkleden & poppenkast</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/muziekinstrumenten/aanbod'>Muziekinstrumenten</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/puzzels/aanbod'>Puzzels</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/poppen-toebehoren/aanbod'>Poppen & toebehoren</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/miniatuurspeelgoed-figuren'>Miniatuurspeelgoed & figuren </a>
        <ul>
            <li class='first last'><a href='/nl/miniatuur-sprookjes-figuren/aanbod'>Miniatuur sprookjes figuren </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/houten-speelgoed'>Houten speelgoed</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/kinderen-houten-speelgoed/aanbod'>Kinderen houten speelgoed</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/voertuigen-knikkerbanen/aanbod'>Voertuigen & knikkerbanen</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/baby-houten-speelgoed/aanbod'>Baby houten speelgoed</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/denkspelletjes/aanbod'>Denkspelletjes</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/juweeltjes-accessoires/aanbod'>Juweeltjes & accessoires</a></li>
    <li class='last  active'><a href='/nl/buitenspeelgoed'>Buitenspeelgoed</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/gezelschapsspellen-buiten/aanbod'>Gezelschapsspellen buiten </a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/zandbakspeelgoed/aanbod'>Zandbakspeelgoed</a></li>
        <li class='active'><a href='/nl/onderzoek-exploreren'>Onderzoek & exploreren </a>
            <ul>
                <li class='first'><a href='/nl/natuur/aanbod'>Natuur </a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href='/nl/technisch/aanbod'>Technisch </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='/nl/waterspelen/aanbod'>Waterspelen</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/rollend-speelgoed/aanbod'>Rollend speelgoed</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/superfoods-raw-foods'>Superfoods & Raw Foods</a><ul>
    <li class='first  active'><a href='/nl/zoete-hartige-snacks-superfood'>Zoete & hartige snacks superfood</a><ul>
        <li class='first last'><a href='/nl/zoet/aanbod'>Zoet</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/superfruit/aanbod'>Superfruit</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/gezonde-vetten/aanbod'>Gezonde vetten</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/rauwe-cacao/aanbod'>Rauwe cacao</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/mixen-in-poeder/aanbod'>Mixen in poeder</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/superfood'>Superfood</a><ul>
        <li><a href='/nl/pitten-noten-zaden/aanbod'>Pitten, Noten & Zaden</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/algen-greens-bijenpollen/aanbod'>Algen, Greens & Bijenpollen</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/natuurlijke-zoetmiddelen/aanbod'>Natuurlijke Zoetmiddelen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/dranken-soepen-superfood'>Dranken & soepen superfood</a><ul>
        <li><a href='/nl/poeders/aanbod'>Poeders</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/supersappen/aanbod'>Supersappen</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/superconcentraten/aanbod'>Superconcentraten</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/nl/boeken-rawfood/aanbod'>Boeken rawfood</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/thee-koffie'>Thee & Koffie</a><ul>
    <li class='first  active'><a href='/nl/kruideninfusie'>Kruideninfusie </a>
        <ul>
            <li class='first'><a href='/nl/kruideninfusie-in-builtjes/aanbod'>Kruideninfusie in builtjes</a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/mixen-losse-kruiden/aanbod'>Mixen & losse kruiden</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/koffie'>Koffie </a>
        <ul>
            <li class='first'><a href='/nl/koffie-bonen/aanbod'>Koffie Bonen</a></li>
            <li><a href='/nl/koffie-gemalen/aanbod'>Koffie Gemalen</a></li>
            <li><a href='/nl/koffie-accessoires/aanbod'>Koffie Accessoires</a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/koffiepads/aanbod'>Koffiepads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/thee-1'>Thee</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/thee-in-builtjes/aanbod'>Thee in builtjes </a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/losse-thee/aanbod'>Losse thee</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/thee-accessoires/aanbod'>Thee accessoires</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/nl/granenkoffiechicorei-koffievervangers/aanbod'>Granenkoffie/chicorei & koffievervangers </a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/nl/vruchtenthee/aanbod'>Vruchtenthee</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/keuken-kruiden'>Keuken & Kruiden</a><ul>
    <li class='first  active'><a href='/nl/kruiden-specerijen'>Kruiden & specerijen</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/anderen-kruiden-1/aanbod'>Anderen kruiden </a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/keukenkruiden-2/aanbod'>Keukenkruiden</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/specerijen/aanbod'>Specerijen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/olien-vetten-azijn'>Oliën, vetten & azijn </a>
        <ul>
            <li class='first'><a href='/nl/azijn/aanbod'>Azijn</a></li>
            <li><a href='/nl/plantaardige-olien/aanbod'>Plantaardige oliën</a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='/nl/plantaardige-vetten/aanbod'>Plantaardige vetten</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/sauzen'>Sauzen</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/koude-sauzen/aanbod'>Koude sauzen</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/plantaardige-romen-kokosmelk/aanbod'>Plantaardige romen & kokosmelk</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/warme-sauzen/aanbod'>Warme sauzen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/smaakmakers'>Smaakmakers</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/bouillons/aanbod'>Bouillons</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/kruidenzout/aanbod'>(Kruiden)zout</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/sojasauzen-oosterse-specialiteiten/aanbod'>Sojasauzen & oosterse specialiteiten</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/nl/zoetmiddelen-4/aanbod'>Zoetmiddelen</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/glutenvrije-voeding'>Glutenvrije voeding</a><ul>
    <li class='first'><a href='/nl/bakbenodigdheden-meelwaren/aanbod'>Bakbenodigdheden & meelwaren</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/beschuiten-crackers/aanbod'>Beschuiten & crackers</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/brood-gebak-2/aanbod'>Brood & gebak</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/broodbeleg-2/aanbod'>Broodbeleg</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/chips-zoutjes/aanbod'>Chips & zoutjes</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/cornflakes-muesli/aanbod'>Cornflakes & muesli</a></li>
    <li><a href='/nl/deegwaren-sauzen/aanbod'>Deegwaren & sauzen</a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/nl/koeken-repen/aanbod'>Koeken & repen</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='active'><a href='/nl/dieetvoeding'>Dieetvoeding</a><ul>
    <li><a href='/nl/dieetvoeding-1/aanbod'>Dieetvoeding</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='/nl/suikerarm'>Suikerarm</a><ul>
        <li class='first'><a href='/nl/broodbeleg-1/aanbod'>Broodbeleg</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/chocolade-1/aanbod'>Chocolade</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/koekjes-snoep/aanbod'>Koekjes & snoep</a></li>
        <li><a href='/nl/peperkoek-fructose/aanbod'>Peperkoek fructose</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='/nl/zoetmiddelen-1/aanbod'>Zoetmiddelen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/nl/zoutarm/aanbod'>Zoutarm</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Now I want to create a new method, in which the markup will be like this example: http://www.bootply.com/DglnYJTSKA#

I have now clue how to do this, can anyone help me out? The output must become someting like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      
      <div id="MainMenu">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 3</a>
          <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
            <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu1">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 a</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 2 b</a>
              <a href="#SubSubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Subitem 3 c <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu list-group-submenu-1" id="SubSubMenu1">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 2</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 4 d</a>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 4</a>
          
           <a href="#demo5" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 5</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="demo5">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I think, thats your job to figure out how it should be done. Looks like standard string building. Same as the previous, only the format is slightly different. Whats the problem you are facing? _instead of.. plz fix my work.._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stefan, look into the TagBuilder() function. Shown below is a menubuilder for a bootstrap menu. You will not be able to use the code directly, as it has callouts to functions not listed, but it should give you an idea of the way you can build a menu from tag objects, adding attributes and classes.

```
       public static MvcHtmlString StaticMenu(this HtmlHelper helper, string activePage, IPrincipal user)
    {
        // Build four containing divs
        var navbarOuter = new TagBuilder("div");
        navbarOuter.AddCssClass("navbar navbar-inverse");
        var navbarInner = new TagBuilder("div");
        navbarInner.AddCssClass("navbar-inner");
        var container = new TagBuilder("div");
        container.AddCssClass("container-fluid");
        var menudiv = new TagBuilder("div");
        menudiv.AddCssClass("nav");

        var home = IconActionLink(helper, "icon-home icon-white", "Home", "Index", "Home", null, null);
        var about = IconActionLink(helper, "icon-info-sign icon-white", "About", "About", "Home", null, null);
        var contact = IconActionLink(helper, "icon-briefcase icon-white", "Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, null);

        var report = new TagBuilder("a");
        var reportUrl = (string)HttpContext.Current.Application["ReportURL"];
        report.MergeAttribute("href", reportUrl.Length > 0 ? reportUrl : "#");
        if (reportUrl.Length > 0) report.MergeAttribute("target", "_blank");
        var reptIcon = new TagBuilder("i");
        reptIcon.MergeAttribute("class", "icon-print icon-white");
        report.InnerHtml = reptIcon + " Reports";

        var menuItems = new TagBuilder("ul");
        menuItems.AddCssClass("nav pull-left");

        //Home Menu
        var menuHome = new TagBuilder("li") { InnerHtml = home.ToHtmlString() };
        if (activePage == "Home") menuHome.AddCssClass("active");

        TagBuilder theMenu;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //Menus Menu
            var menuService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMenuService>().GetMainMenu();
            theMenu = new TagBuilder("li") { InnerHtml = GenerateMenu(helper, menuService, user, activePage).ToString() };
            about = null;
            contact = null;
        }
        else
        {
            theMenu = null;
        }

        //About Menu
        var menuAbout = (about != null) ? new TagBuilder("li") { InnerHtml = about.ToHtmlString() } : null;
        if (menuAbout != null && activePage == "About") menuAbout.AddCssClass("active");

        //Contact Menu
        var menuContact = (contact != null) ? new TagBuilder("li") { InnerHtml = contact.ToHtmlString() } : null;
        if (menuContact != null && activePage == "Contact") menuContact.AddCssClass("active");

        //Report Menu
        var menuReport = new TagBuilder("li") { InnerHtml = report.ToString() };

        menuItems.InnerHtml = menuHome.ToString();
        menuItems.InnerHtml += (menuAbout != null) ? menuAbout.ToString() : "";
        menuItems.InnerHtml += (menuContact != null) ? menuContact.ToString() : "";
        menuItems.InnerHtml += (theMenu != null) ? theMenu.ToString() : "";
        menuItems.InnerHtml += menuReport;

        // nest our divs
        menudiv.InnerHtml += menuItems;
        container.InnerHtml = menudiv.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        navbarInner.InnerHtml = container.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        navbarOuter.InnerHtml = navbarInner.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return new MvcHtmlString(navbarOuter.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Good Luck.